# Best practices for category page optimization onsite SEO

Tags: seo, website-promotion

I want to optimize the category page to best possible way so that Google crawls and give weightage to listing page. I have page `http://www.example.com/flowers/`.

So can you please provide few guidelines for this. As *schema.org* do not have any guidelines for listing page.